# PHP file displaying same JSON after change

Tags: php, android, json

I have a strange problem with my app.
I have a PHP file on my server that echoes a JSON and I am fetching it from Android app.

If i change the PHP file, then also it gives the same JSON i dont know why and how.

If I fetch the file from browser, it displays correct JSON.

And now when i rename the file it displays the correct output.

I am fed up with this behavior.
Somebody please help.

Comment: Caching could possibly play a part in this.

Comment: Is the JSON dynamic or static?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947772/json-being-cached-by-android-application

Comment: I change the JSON manually by altering the file

Comment: What service are you using to connect to the file?

Comment: I am using HttpGet

Comment: You need to force the cache, have you tried that?

Comment: What does force cache means?

Comment: Putting headers to your request.

Comment: It sounds like a caching issue, but I don't see anything on the receiving end which would implement client-side caching.

Comment: A Cache is a storage system used to save a file or image for example. Then a client doesn't have to retrieve it from the internet every time.

Comment: @apokryfos httpGet caches by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a caching issue. There are number of different options you can try to bust the caching.

One method that pretty much always works is to place a random query string value to end of the URL. Something like a `timestamp` is a good option as it is always new but a random string works too.

For example, if you URL was:

```
https://my.site/getJSON.php
```

The new URL would be:

```
https://my.site/getJSON.php?t=<timestamp or random string>
```

Other options include adding `Cache-Control` headers (and more) but the query string trick works and is easy to implement.

Comment: I added System.nanoTime() as the time stamp. It worked. Thanks. Tigger 

Comment: if I use HttpPost then this caching issue should not happen isn't?

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee To be honest I'm not sure as this is up the to how caching code is written. One thing I do know is that the random string on the query string makes to the URL unique and therefore can not (should not) be cached.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Comment: What will it do? I am not that experienced in PHP.

Comment: Basically it will force the HTTP client to fetch a fresh copy of the JSON File from your server. Rather than utilising the local one that it saved.

Comment: Also this snippet will need to go into your Android App. Not the PHP file

Comment: Or you can specify in the Headers of your PHP file that Applications shouldn't cache the file.

Comment: Equivalent in PHP `header("Cache-control: no-cache");` and/or 
  `header("Pragma: no-cache");` for HTTP 1.0

Comment: Try adding `header("Cache-control: no-cache");` to the top of the php file